# Directories containing .jpg files were converted to binary files [shutil]

Tags: python, subdirectory, shutil, os.path

**Update:**

Basically, I want to divide a large folder into 2 groups.
The large folder is made up of 120 subfolders. An example subfolder name would be ***n02085620-Chihuahua***. n02085620-Chihuahua has 152 .jpg files. An example file in it would be **n02085620_7.jpg**. You see **n02085620** is the same.

Names of files that should go to group #1 are given in `sample_submission.csv`. Other files should invariably go to group #2. Each file should be inside its respective mother folder.

**Initial post:**

I want to copy 8580 .img files to 120 folders.

I'm using shutil to achieve that.
My main folder is
`source = '/Users/turuud/Desktop/TUT/Dscience_exp/Images/'`
while my destination folder looks like this:

`test_path = '/Users/turuud/Desktop/TUT/Dscience_exp/test/'`

The destination folder should include 120 sub-folders. I'm using os.path.join to achieve that.

The problem is that I'm not getting 120 directories with embedded images belonging to them. Instead, I'm getting 120 binary files that can't be used the way they are.

Below is the entire code:

```
import os
import csv
import shutil

source = '/Users/turuud/Desktop/TUT/Dscience_exp/Images/'
testcsv = '/Users/turuud/Desktop/TUT/Dscience_exp/sample_submission.csv'
test_path = '/Users/turuud/Desktop/TUT/Dscience_exp/test/'

with open(testcsv, 'r') as file:
  csvreader = csv.reader(file)
  next(csvreader)
  for row in csvreader:
    for directory in os.listdir(source):
        if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(source, directory)):
            for img_file in os.listdir(os.path.join(source, directory)):
              if str(row[0]) == str(img_file):
                print(f"{row[0]} and {img_file} are exactly same")
                shutil.copy(os.path.join(source, directory, img_file), os.path.join(test_path, directory))
```

[image]
[image]

In the folder "test", I want to have directories that include their respective files. No binary files.

This is the result when last line of the code:

```
shutil.copy(os.path.join(source, directory, img_file), os.path.join(test_path, directory))
```

is changed to

```
shutil.copy(os.path.join(source, directory, img_file), test_path)
```

[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAI6d.png)

I wanted them embedded in their mother folders.

Comment: Check [`shutil.copytree()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree), seems like you reimplementing it.

Comment: Hello, but the documentation says "copytree" is used for recursively copying everything inside a directory. I don't think my case applies to this. You know I have if conditions. Correct files should be copied to the subfolders inside the destination folder.

Comment: I wish my mother tongue was English so that I can convey what I exactly want better.

Comment: Maybe make 2 directories with 3 files each and use that as a simple example. Then, before you do anything in your code, assign the input and output files/directories to variables and print a line saying what you are about to run. Make it easy for folks to help you. Thank you.

Comment: It's not too complicated. Please look at: ```shutil.copy(os.path.join(source, directory, img_file), os.path.join(test_path, directory))```. ```os.path.join(test_path, directory)``` is not creating dog breed directories.  ```test_path``` works but I don't get the directories which I will need in model training.

Comment: In this context,```directory``` is a variable. I see a pattern in that the destination folder is always constant in the documentation. I don't wanna write 120 lines of paths. Do you understand?

Comment: @Ori, indeed it's quite comlicated for understanding. You need to at least describe program logic more explicit, because now I see that you want to copy tree from one folder to another leaving only files listed in CSV.

Comment: @OlvinRoght Yes2, you are right. What would you do if you were me?

Comment: @OlvinRoght Slava Ukraine, btw.

Comment: @MarkSetchell please come look

Comment: @Ori, does [this simplified example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0ygQ.png) represents what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Ori, or maybe [another simplified example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhqbX.png) fits better?

Comment: @OlvinRoght  Hey, thank you. **another simplified example** sums up correctly. How did you draw this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd start from simplifying task. Let's say we have next file structure:

```
│   rules.csv
│
└───source
    ├───1
    │       1.jpg
    │       2.jpg
    │
    ├───2
    │       3.jpg
    │       4.jpg
    │
    ├───3
    │       5.jpg
    │       6.jpg
    │
    ├───4
    │       7.jpg
    │       8.jpg
    │
    └───5
            10.jpg
            9.jpg
```

And `rules.csv` has next content:

```
1.jpg
2.jpg
5.jpg
9.jpg
```

Our python script should create folder `result` with two subfolders `group_1` and `group_2` with next structure:

```
└───result
    ├───group_1
    │   ├───1
    │   │       1.jpg
    │   │       2.jpg
    │   │
    │   ├───3
    │   │       5.jpg
    │   │
    │   └───5
    │           9.jpg
    │
    └───group_2
        ├───2
        │       3.jpg
        │       4.jpg
        │
        ├───3
        │       6.jpg
        │
        ├───4
        │       7.jpg
        │       8.jpg
        │
        └───5
                10.jpg
```

To make this we need firstly to load CSV and save first column of every row *(which is filename)*, I'll use `set` as a container. Then we need to iterate over child folders of source folder and save filenames which exists in CSV to *group_1* folder and others to *group_2* folder.

```py
import csv
from pathlib import Path
from shutil import copy2

source_dir = Path(r"C:\Users\Ori\Pictures")
rules_path = r"C:\Users\Ori\Documents\rules.csv"
result_dir = Path(r"C:\Users\Ori\Pictures\sorted")

group_1_dir = result_dir / "group_1"
group_2_dir = result_dir / "group_2"

with open(rules_path) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    # next(reader)
    group_1_files = {row[0] for row in reader}

for path in source_dir.iterdir():
    if path.is_dir():
        for file in path.iterdir():
            if file.is_file():
                if file.name in group_1_files:
                    destination = group_1_dir / file.relative_to(source_dir)
                else:
                    destination = group_2_dir / file.relative_to(source_dir)
                destination.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
                copy2(file, destination)
```

Also you can use [`.glob()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) to find all `.jpg` files, it is more universal in case if depth can be more than 2:

```py
import csv
from pathlib import Path
from shutil import copy2

source_dir = Path(r"C:\Users\Ori\Pictures")
rules_path = r"C:\Users\Ori\Documents\rules.csv"
result_dir = Path(r"C:\Users\Ori\Pictures\sorted")

group_1_dir = result_dir / "group_1"
group_2_dir = result_dir / "group_2"

with open(rules_path) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    # next(reader)
    group_1_files = {row[0] for row in reader}

for jpg in source_dir.glob(r"*\*.jpg"):
    if jpg.name in group_1_files:
        destination = group_1_dir / jpg.relative_to(source_dir)
    else:
        destination = group_2_dir / jpg.relative_to(source_dir)
    destination.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    copy2(file, destination)
```